# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Getting following error while running maven test on project.
I am building a test application using Spring Data Neo4j.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 70 in XML document from class path resource [konvoy-test-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:205)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:2525)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.java:74)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.traverseAttrsAndAttrGrps(XSDAbstractTraverser.java:633)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:1059)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:279)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:133)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:214)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1258)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:579)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2408)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1753)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:377)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2740)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:645)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:508)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 42 more
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1fa1bb6] to prepare test instance [com.konvoy.test.UserTest@1901437]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 70 in XML document from class path resource [konvoy-test-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:205)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:2525)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.java:74)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.traverseAttrsAndAttrGrps(XSDAbstractTraverser.java:633)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:1059)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:279)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:133)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:214)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1258)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:579)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2408)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1753)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:377)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2740)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:645)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:508)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
```

Application Context File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.konvoy"/>

    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.konvoy.repository"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.konvoy.services"/>


   <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown"/> 

    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/> -->
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: I've just had this issue when deploying on Heroku (whereas working well locally). Waited for 10 minutes and that reworked. ^^

Comment: I am trying since week but this is yet to get resolved.

Comment: For information, I use neo4j 1.9M04, Spring-Data-Neo4J 2.2.0.Release, neo4j-rest-graphdb 1.9M04, Spring core 3.2.0, Spring-commons 1.5.0

Comment: I encountered the same problem recently and starts to make me crazy. For some reason a spring-mongodb web application that I haven't changed for months throws the exception above on startup. A different project with the same setup works without problems. None of the answers did help. Anyone with a better idea or explanation?

Answer (score 14):

Haven't figured out the underlying cause, but I got a solution.

I had the same problem with spring-data-mongodb, using next versions:

- spring-data-mongodb : 1.2.0.RELEASE
- spring-data-commons : 1.5.0.RELEASE (inherited from spring-data-mongodb)
- spring-data-commons-core : 1.4.0.RELEASE (overriding managed version 1.2.0.RELEASE, to fix a different issue)

**The way I solved it:**

Just add these guys to your schemaLocation attribute of the XMLSchemaInstance namespace (most likely xsi:schemaLocation) in your Spring config xml file:

- http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd

For example, my Spring config xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd">
...
</beans>
```

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try add dependency to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and check

http://www.springsource.org/node/3811

Comment: Thanks Michail for you suggestions, but it still did not work.

Comment: Which version of spring data neo4j are you using? Try 2.2.0.RELEASE which has a dependency to spring-data-commons 1.5.0.RELEASE. The missing "auditing-attributes" attribute was added in the 1.5 release, so it should be found.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with mongo.

The solution has been to put the version of "xsd" in "xsi: schemaLocation", if not resolved the issue, try going down version of "xsd", the latter is not the best but it works.

In my case, before KO:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context         
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">
```

...mongo/spring-mongo.xsd

OK now:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context         
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">
```

...mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your application context file (konvoy-test-context.xml) so we can see what you're trying to accomplish?

These are the tags you usually use to configure neo4j in Spring Data Neo4j:

```
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="${graphDb.dir}" />
<neo4j:repositories base-package="your.package" />
```

Comment: I suspect, something is missing in pom.xml. but could not figure it out, what it is?

Comment: Try changing the repositories to one line like e.g. <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.konvoy"/>

Answer (score 0):

This occurs usually when you are lacking the spring-data-commons jar. Include the jar in your lib directory or using maven. It should work. Get the jar from the following directory if you are not using maven:

http://www.springsource.org/download/community

Spring Data Core-->
spring-data-commons-1.5.1.jar

Should also include the following jar:

Spring Data JPA-->spring-data-jpa-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar

This should work with Spring release 3.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by delete dependence

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```